# ag-grid not showing any data

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, rendering, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid with angularjs. so in controller I am populating rows of grid with the sql DB source. For this I am making webapi call which returns array of object. Following is the code.

```
var module = angular.module("crud", ["agGrid"]);

module.controller("crudCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
var columnDefs = [
   { headerName: "Roll No", field: "RollNo", editable: true },
   { headerName: "Name", field: "Name", editable: true },
   { headerName: "Place", field: "PlaceName", editable: true },
   { headerName: "Birth Date", field: "dob", editable: true }
];


$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: [],
    headerHeight: 42,
    rowHeight: 32

};

$http.get("api/Student/GetAllStudents").then(function (response) {
    $scope.gridOptions.rowData = response.data;

}, function (error) {
    console.log('Oops! Something went wrong while saving the data.')
});


});
```

but when I run the page it is not showing any data. When I debug and see it returns records in response.data as an array of object as array[12]. but it is not showing the same in grid. If instead of response.data I assign my own array similar to what response returns, then it renders the data. So, where is the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had a similar problem. You may need to use gridOptions.onGridReady

```
        onGridReady: () => {
            //setup first yourColumnDefs and yourGridData

            //now use the api to set the columnDefs and rowData
            this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(yourColumnDefs);
            this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(yourGridData);
        },
```

Comment: thanx... but in my case it got solved by $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(res.data);

Comment: Might be a difference between adding data and replacing it with a new array. I added the setRowData() call after receiving new data, not in the onGridReady function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the columnDefs field matches the fields in your rowData array.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure rowModelType as 'serverSide' in gridOptions if the data comes from server, otherwise the rowModelType as '' for loading data from local.

Comment: You only need to set the rowModelType to `serverSide` if you are using that row model where only a subset of the data is loaded into the grid at a time. I.e all the data is kept in the server and the grid only requests the next set of rows when the grid scrolls / is filtered.

By default, and as the question above requires, the ClientSide row model is used where all the data is provided to the Grid.